# ArcGIS Pro WFS Authentication via HTTP Headers

Tags: arcgis-pro, wfs, authentication

I am currently trying to connect to a WFS server on ArcGIS pro. I have a token for authentication, and adding it to custom request parameters here just appends it to the URL. Is there no way to create a custom Authorization header to add the key?

For reference, QGIS allows creation of custom authentication and wondered if ArcGIS had a similar feature (newbie)

[image]

Comment: add your &token in the custom request parameters - like https://youtu.be/7IC9g9P61zw?si=-vofonbAOIoR9Y0T&t=69

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was more so injecting the token into the Authorization headers but with ArcGIS locked down, there was no way to do this. So I went with the approach that @Mapperz mentioned where I added a token within the custom request parameters.